# Inter Application communication using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line-arguments, tcplistener

I have a softphone developed with C# WinForms...
Now I want to add XMPP chat also with it... 
But the problem is I am afraid to add XMPP feature also to always-busy-threaded softphone... 
I suspect if any perfomance fail will come... So My questions are...

- Can I add some XMPP forms to the current application running in
  seperate processes ??
- If I make Softphone and XMPP as different applications; I need to
  update the presence status of XMPP as (Available, On Call, Ringing,
  Busy Now etc automatically as the person uses Softphpne)
- How can I send the current status from Softphone to XMPP if it is
  different application? Which is the best way ?

  ```
  Should I use TCP Listeners (That will give extra work to the
  ```

  Softphone)

  or, I should use command-line parameters (Using Single instance of XMPP, Dont know        about Perfomance)

Comment: have you looked into WCF? why not create a service maybe

Comment: WCF ?? These are just two winform applications, and i want to just share some text showing the status,,, and it should be easily installed by the customer too,,,